# putting numbers in an array into arraylist

Tags: c#, winforms, arrays, arraylist, mergesort

i have numbers that user enter in textBox3 and i converted them to an array nums now i want to put half of them in arraylist A and half of them in arraylist B how can i do that?thanks

```
 string[] source = textBox3.Text.Split(',');

 int[] nums = new int[source.Length];

 for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
 {
     nums[i] = Convert.ToInt32(source[i]);
 }

   ArrayList A = new ArrayList();

   ArrayList B = new ArrayList();
```

edited:

thanks,i tested your answers but output of all of your codes are system.collection.generic[system.int32],whats the problem?thanks

for example i tested this that ArsenMkrt wrote:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] source = textBox3.Text.Split(',');
        int[] nums = new int[source.Length];

List<int> A = nums.Take(source.Length/2).ToList();

List<int> B = nums.Skip(source.Length/2).ToList();


            MessageBox.Show(B.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: it should be system.collection.generic[system.int32] cause we create generic lists, if you want ArrayList, try my first version of answer, or use .ToArray() expect of .ToList() to get arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not recommended using array list because of boxing issues so use lists:

```
List<int> lst1 = new List<int>();
lst1.AddRange(nums.Skip(nums.Length/2));

List<int> lst2 = new List<int>();
lst2.AddRange(nums.Take(nums.Length / 2));
```

first list contains length/2 to length and second list contains first item to length / 2

**Edit:** See [101 linq sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746) for interducing to linq.

**Edit:** for showing the items in list should traverse list, list.ToString() returns type of list See [MSDN ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) not items, so you should override it and use your specific list or do:

```
foreach (var i in lsss)
{
  MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
}
```

Or

```
lst1.ForEach(x=>MessageBox.Show(x.ToString()));
```

Or

```
string strList = "";
lst1.ForEach(x => strList += x + " , ");
MessageBox.Show(strList);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   string[] source = textBox3.Text.Split(',');
   var nums = source.Select(s=>Convert.ToInt32(s));

   ArrayList A = new ArrayList(nums.Take(source.Length/2));

   ArrayList B = new ArrayList(nums.Skip(source.Length/2));
```

Or to have generic List which is more faster for value types, you can write

```
  List<int> A = nums.Take(source.Length/2).ToList();

  List<int> B = nums.Skip(source.Length/2)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
 {
 if(i < nums.Length / 2) A.Add(nums[i]);
         else B.Add(nums[i]);
 }
```

This will work in all .NETs. Consider using generic `List<int>`, you will avoid  boxing/unboxing and possible `InvalidCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList A = new ArrayList();

ArrayList B = new ArrayList(); 

for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++) 
{
     if(i % 2 == 1)
          A.Add(Convert.ToInt32(source[i]));
     else
          B.Add(Convert.ToInt32(source[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming array length is even

```
 ArrayList A = new ArrayList();  
 ArrayList B = new ArrayList();     
 int backword = source.Length / 2;
 int forward = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < source.Length/2; i++) 
  {   

   A.Add(Convert.ToInt32(source[++forward]));
   A.Add(Convert.ToInt32(source[++backword]));


 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that cause out of range exception?

Comment: you should do: for (int i = 0; i < source.Length / 2; i++), backward will causes to exception.

Comment: ohh , yes .. i were typing very fast .. but corrected the code